# How come I cannot install tidyverse in RStudio?

Tags: r

When I type

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

I get the following

```
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dtplyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/dtplyr’
ERROR: dependency ‘broom’ is not available for package ‘modelr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/modelr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘modelr’, ‘rvest’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tidyverse’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/dp/4s8zzfmn11v13_xvl38yygcr0000gn/T/RtmpSbkirG/downloaded_packages’
There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I cannot figure out why tidyverse won't install on my laptop but did on my PC.
I have the latest version of R as well.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like you have the latest R version, which is currently 4.2.2 and not 4.0.*.

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring section with: Ctrl + Shift + F10